# regular expression with recursion in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, recursion

I'm trying to use this but can't make it work. I want to check the syntax of expressions like this: (1+2)*(3+4)

I have integers, +, * and brackets. That's it, but it can be nested to any depth.

In BNF syntax the expr can be described like this:

```
expr
<sum>
sum
<product>{+<product>}
product
<atom>{*<atom>}
atom
<number>|(<expr>)
number
<digit>{<digit>}
```

I tried to translate this to Perl like this:

```
$number = '\d+';
$atom = "($number|\\((?R)\\))";
$product = "$atom(\\*$atom)*";
$sum = "$product(\\+$product)*";
$expr = $sum;
if ('(1+2)*(3+4)' =~ /^$expr$/)
{
    print "OK";
}
```

But it doesn't match! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @toolic That's to avoid collapsing escape, right? But I have doubled the \ as you can see so...

Answer (score 5):

When you recurse, the `^` at the start of the pattern will fail to match.

Use `(?(DEFINE)...)` to define the rules instead of using `(?R)`.

```
'(1+2)*(3+4)' =~ /
   ^ (?&expr) \z

   (?(DEFINE)
      # Rules.
      (?<expr>    (?&sum)                            )
      (?<sum>     (?&product) (?: \+ (?&product) )*+ )
      (?<product> (?&atom)    (?: \* (?&atom)    )*+ )
      (?<atom>    (?&NUMBER) | \( (?&expr) \)        )

      # Tokens.
      (?<NUMBER> \d++ )
   )
/x
   or die("Doesn't match.\n");
```

which simplifies to

```
'(1+2)*(3+4)' =~ /
   ^ (?&expr) \z

   (?(DEFINE)
      # Rules.
      (?<expr>      (?&binary_op)                  )
      (?<binary_op> (?&atom) (?: [+*] (?&atom) )*+ )
      (?<atom>      (?&NUMBER) | \( (?&expr) \)    )

      # Tokens.
      (?<NUMBER> \d++ )
   )
/x
   or die("Doesn't match.\n");
```

That's assuming you're only trying to check for validity rather than trying to parse the string. If you need to parse the string, you can build a parser using Parse::RecDescent or Marpa::R2.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable contribution. I didn't know about this DEFINE stuff. I've got some questions: Does the regex end with /x and incorporate the whole DEFINE section? Does /x mean extension? Is white space not significant? What does \z mean? You have a + at the end of <sum> and <product>, what does it mean? You can't combine + and * like that because it violates precedence: 1*2+3*4 will then be parsed at the first * which is wrong.

Comment: You're probably right about the ^ at the start of my regex and $ at the end, but if I drop them, how do I match the whole string and not just a part of it? My string matches if I drop them but then even A(1+2)*(3+4)B matches!

Comment: Re "*Does the regex end with `/x` and incorporate the whole DEFINE section? Does `/x` mean extension? Is white space not significant?*" `/x` makes whitespace insignificant in the entire pattern except in character classes (`[]`) and when escaped. See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: Re "*What does `\z` mean?*", End of string. (`$` does not mean end of string.)  See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: Re "*You have a + at the end of <sum> and <product>*", An optimization. Prevents the `*` is modifies from attempting to match fewer times during backtracking. See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: Re "*You can't combine + and * like that because it violates precedence*", Precedence only matters when parsing (which you aren't doing). It doesn't matter if `1*2+3*4` means `(1*2)+(3*4)` or `((1*2)+3)*4` when you're only checking if `1*2+3*4` is legal (which you are doing).

Comment: Re "*if I drop them, how do I match the whole string and not just a part of it?*", Who said anything about dropping `^` and `$`? (Well, ok, I dropped `$` in favour of the more appropriate `\z`, but you get the point.) They're not the problem. The problem is that you recursed the entire pattern instead of the correct part. I showed a solution.

Comment: Appreciate the info :). But hey, I am capturing quite a lot of things! And I could easily capture more by inserting more brackets. So the parsing is important. I know I recursed the whole pattern, but how does one recurse just a part? (?R) recurses the whole regex it's part of. Your solution is nice but how do I change my code minimally to solve this problem with ^ and $   ?

Comment: No, You can't easily capture more. You could capture at most one atom, etc. This approach won't work if you want to parse. I made a couple of recommendations in my post if you do want to parse. /// To recurse just a part, you can specify a capture to recurse (see perlre for details), or you can use the approach I used in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

ikegami's workaround above with the DEFINE stuff is beautiful, but it doesn't answer the question how to do it my way. A minimal change of my code to make it work? ikegami is right, the cause of no match is the ^ in /^$expr$/ . When the parser reenters the regex recursively it again checks for beginning of string, which fails. So I cannot have ^ and $ in the regex it seems. Without them my string matches. But then some invalid strings match too, like A(1+2)*(3+4)B . In the absence of ^ and $ it doesn't necessarily match the whole string. Problem.

ikegami suggested a solution to this in a comment above. I'll just write it out. I have tested it and it works:

```
$number = '\d+';
$atom = "($number|\\((?1)\\))";
$product = "$atom(\\*$atom)*";
$sum = "$product(\\+$product)*";
$expr = $sum;
if ('(1+2)*(3+4)' =~ /^($expr)$/)
{
    print "OK";
}
```

Notice that I now have (?1) instead of (?R) and that I have enclosed $expr in brackets. (?1) refers to the first capture group, which is ($expr). So the recursion reenters this subex instead of the whole regex. ^ is not met again. That solves it.